# is there an "app store" for regular pc apps?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have writen an app for the computer in java, but i don't want to give it out for free. I only want to charge somewhere between $0.99 - $2.99, is there a website that i can upload it to, to do this for me. I am looking for something like the apple app store, or the android market, but for the computer. Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search came up with [this](http://allmyapps.com/). Allmyapps is a place where you can buy and sell applications (Windows only, as far as I can see), and it also seems that it can manage the installation process (for example, combining the installation of several apps into one, thus making system rebuilding very easy).

Check out their terms of service for developers [here](http://developers.allmyapps.com/). As I can see, you can sign up for free, and keep 80% of sales revenues.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be moved to [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but the only PC "app store" I'm aware of is Intel's [AppUp](http://www.appup.com/).